# Reusing temporary tables in Spark SQL 2.0 in different sessions

Tags: session, apache-spark-sql

I would like to emulate smth like a global temporary table in Spark SQL 2.0, namely register some RDD as a temporary table in parent context, and afterwards reuse it in Spark SQL Sessions. In Sessions I am going to register further temporary tables, which must remain locally visible in that particular session.

Are there any workaround for that?

Regards

Michael

Comment: Why not converting the RDD to as DataFrame and saving it as a table using [DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@saveAsTable(tableName:String):Unit)?

Comment: saveAsTable saves new hive table. The idea is, that this table stays in memory :)